# Calling a private super class constructor implicitly from the subclass results in random behavior

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

```
package pack1;
public class Outer{
    private Outer(){}
}

package pack2;
import pack1.*;
public class ExtendedOuter extends Outer{
        //compiler adds default no-args constructor, something like this
        /*
        public ExtendedOuter(){
             super(){}
        }
        */
}

now from a third class

import pack1.Outer;
import pack2.ExtendedOuter;
class InnerClasses{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ExtendedOuter o=new ExtendedOuter();
    }
}
```

but hey, 
`Outer`'s constructor is private , so you would expect this code to not compile, but it does compile fine.
only at runtime we know we goofed up when it throws `IllegalAccessError`
but this only happens sometimes ! 
sometimes you do get a error `Outer() is private` , sometimes you don't get error
how does one explain such random behavior ?

But private method invocation is warned at compile time. so why not when it comes to implcitly added constructors?
PS: the compiler does throw error `Outer() is private in Outer class` if you explicitly add a constructor `ExtendedOuter(){}` in `ExtendedOuter` class

**EDIT----------------------**

I am sorry but this makes no sense. Its indeed unpredictable and outcomes differ from one compilation to other
Surprise
OK if this doesn't work , try switching the modifier of Outer constructor from `private` to `public` 
ok , now it works and compiles
now switch the modifier to `private` again, compiles again ! it shouldn't have, no? but run it and u will encounter an `IllegalAccessError`

now after sometime, it cud happen that it even doesn't compile with `private` showing the typical message `Outer() is not public in Outer class`
great . now switch the modifier of `Outer()` constructor to public again, compiles ! now switch it to `private` again, compiles (whereas previously it wasn't compiling)

Try it out yourself and let me know 
but don't forget to compile javac with -cp

Comment: It doesn't compile. You cannot extend a class with no accessible constructors.

Comment: @Sarabjeet, what compiler are you using?

Comment: You're probably not recompiling all the classes. Of course, if you first compile the subclass when Outer has a public constructor, and then change the Outer class to have a private constructor and recompile Outer only, the subclass won't be modified, and will throw an exception at runtime. Make sure to recompile all the classes after each change.

Comment: well I don't think thats the problem JB Nizet, as I just now inserted a new method in `ExtendedOuter` and just saved it, but didn't compile `ExtendedOuter` and when i access the method from mainclass, it works fine . I think all classes linked to main class are automatically recompiled

Comment: @Sarabjeet please accept an answer to your question instead of leaving it unfinished. I am not asking you to select my answer of course, but it would help other people to know the answer you eventually accepted. If the answer isn't posted yet, please make and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really two questions. Unfortunately, due to that nature of the questions, these answers are somewhat speculative. Here are the questions I believe you want answered:

> What are the compilation mechanics of private constructors being
>   referenced from auto-generated default constructors?

If you make the constructor of a class `private`, that class cannot be sub-classed. A `private` constructor is as effective a way to prevent sub-classing as the `final` keyword; all subclasses will be forced via `super()` to attempt to call an unreachable constructor. Because the `ExtendedOuter` class only references the `private` constructor of the `Outer` class implicitly (via generated constructor code) the compiler does not seem to be aware you are attempting to call an unreachable constructor.

It would seem your compiler fails to consider the side-effects of default constructor generation. However, on recompilation of your classes, the compiler may be taking the shortcut of using available class bytecode from previous compilations. That bytecode reuse might explain how subsequent recompilations correctly identify the unreachable constructor. What your compiler cannot determine via code analysis it can determine via bytecode analysis (hypothetically of course, I can't be sure without access to your exact compiler/machine/etc).

> Why does my execution of the provided class structure generate
>   IllegalAccessError non-deterministically despite no changes to the
>   compiled code?

If you look at your `Outer` class, the constructor contains no branches or method calls that would prevent it's removal as an optimization. The generated default constructor of `ExtendedOuter` may also be subject to optimistic removal by the JIT compiler. To fully answer this question would require determining what the JIT compiler is likely to determine about the method and constructor calls.

The JIT compiler is a complicated topic, but it isn't unlikely that an empty constructor call could be inlined or even completely replaced by a no-op transparently by the JIT compiler. If the JIT compiler were making code replacements and optimizations, that could easily lead to inconsistent code paths across multiple executions of the program. The JVM and it's JIT compiler are not guaranteed to produce a deterministic output.

Comment: Thanks Emily, but now if I do get asked in my certification exam, What should be the output of such a program, what could I choose between two options : compilation fails OR exception is thrown at Runtime

Comment: @Sarabjeet I would say the most correct answer is that an `Error` (not an `Exception`) is generated at run-time. I believe this may be an example of the halting problem, in which case it is impossible for the compiler to correctly evaluate the code as being in error with 100% accuracy. Essentially, the most definite statement I think that could be made is that if the constructors are executed, then an `Error` is generated. I would strongly recommend that you reference the Java Language Specification on this topic, as I am not 100% confident and I don't want to mislead you and hurt your score.

Comment: I can't find anywhere in JLS. can u please help me find

Comment: The rules that apply to constructor access can be found within [JLS §6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1).

Answer (score -1):

If you try to create the object of a class having private constructor, the compiler throws error because object creation is detected during compile time which is not possible. In your case constructor has to be invoked in order to validate the object creation. When an object of  class `ExtendedOuter` is created compiler checks for its default constructor which is available. No method is invoked during compile time. While at runtime, constructor of class `Outer` is invoked which results in `IllegalAccessError`.
Random behaviour of compiler is still not clear to me. Are you doing any code change before compilation? Can you throw light on the exact steps you are carrying out in order to test your code?

Comment: This does not answer the question.